# Android: Animation and TextView performance issue

Tags: android, performance, animation, textview

I am developing a native android game. I have several test devices. My application works very slowly at one of them (HTC One m7,Android 5.0.2). I found two main reasons that slow my application:

- First main reason is using setText method of TextView (called every second in a timer).
  When I remove setText methods from the code, application works fine. Setting static text is also slow. I am sure that problem is setText method itself.
- Second main reason is several animations in layout (AnimationDrawable).

After some research, some people think that setting TextView dimensions to exact values while using setText method solves the problem. I tried that but it did not work.

To solve animation issue I tried to use android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in AndroidManifest file. It did not work as well.

At other test devices, my application works perfectly fine also at another Android Lollipop device. Problematic activity has lots of views and layouts.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Here's some more advanced post about `TextView`'s performance, maybe it will help you: http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/114508858967/improving-comment-rendering-on-android

Comment: Thanks for reply but it did not solve the issue. Moreover setting my custom view's onDraw method totally empty did not improve performance (these textviews are empty without rendering texts). Animations and calling setText methods cost so much.

Comment: Calling setText method cost much (as 10%) and animations cost so much (90%). I forgot to write that my activity has two scrollViews one is vertical and in it there is another horizontal scrollView. My activity layout includes some custom layouts. OnMeasure method of these custom layouts are overriden. Other methods are same as super class.

Comment: You would need to post outline of how it looks and what do you do with these text views, I'm afraid. Animations may very well be a problem, but if we don't know the layouts and animations themselves, I can't think of anything